# Does Apple Pay supports Auto Renew Subscriptions

Tags: in-app-purchase, subscription, applepay

I had integrated **Apple pay** in my app. I want to know that if Apple pay allows the auto renew subscriptions.

I have an app in which there are 5-6 subscription packages. All the subscriptions and there working are different. These include monthly and daily subscriptions. And for the payment, I was adding the  subscriptions that user select and does the payment through Apple pay. This is **advised** by my client.

Now the issue is, the client wants that those subscriptions should **auto renew** after their subscription ends. The auto renew subscription thing happens in **In-app purchases**. Can we also do auto renew with the apple pay. If no, what can be the possible solution for this.

Comment: What about StoreKit subscriptions? Depending on what you are selling Apple Pay would likely not be allowed.